# how to transfer joomla localhost from mac to pc?

Tags: joomla

i have been working on a joomla site on my localhost in my mac.The folder is called "mysite"
Now i want to transfer the site to my pc. I copied "mysite" folder from my mac's MAMP application and pasted the folder in my pc (C:\WAMP\www\mysite)

When i try to launch localhost\mysite, there is an error message "Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL."

I dont understand what the problem is.

Pls advice if you know what i missed out or perhaps a better way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla cannot connect to your database.  Open and inspect the `mysite\configuration.php` file.  Depending on what version of Joomla you're using, the layout will differ, but your MySQL connection is not correct and should look something like below.  Adjust the values accordingly and that should do it.

```
public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'root';
public $password = 'password';
```

Comment: Wow! you are awesome! The problem is indeed with the config file. to make things easier, i copied the file from an existing test site that i have and changed the few parameters you mentioned and it works! Thanks so much